# Autocomplete not giving results of JSon file

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

I'm attempting to use autocomplete to give me back of list of 'providers'. The only results that will show through trial and error is '[object object]'. Everything else is 'no search results'. Could someone point me in a direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

edit: This is being used locally. No web server etc.

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
                <input id="searchfield" />
                <input type="submit" name="go" value="go!" />
            </form>


<script src='js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/autocomplete/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/Providers.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var cat_data = $.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                    ProviderID: item.ProviderID,
                    Name: item.Name,                  
                };
            });
            $("#searchfield").autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                source: cat_data,
                minlength:0
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

json format

```
   {"Providers":[{"ProviderID":"3","NAME":"name1"}, 
    {"ProviderID":"4","NAME":"name2"},  
    {"ProviderID":"5","NAME":"name3"}]}
```

Comment: Try `$.map(data.Providers, function(item) {`

Comment: get a TypeError: this.source is not a function in Firefox and a SCRIPT5007: Object expected in explorer

Comment: Try console.log(data) and also check the cat_data var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `data` to `data.Providers`, Also there are some other errors

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/Providers.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var cat_data = $.map(data.Providers, function(item) {
                return {
                    value: item.ProviderID,
                    label: item.NAME

                };
            });
            $("#searchfield").autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                source: cat_data,
                minlength:0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: '[object object]' is still what only gives results only now it actually recognizes the file. Says 27159 results but only when I type characters '[object object]'. It wont recognize "name1" etc. Then loads 27159 bullets below with no name next to them

Comment: updated code gives all results now typing any character regardles if characters are in file. ex: asdf gives all results. Still formated as bullets not actually listing names

Comment: it works! thank you so much, been hacking at this thing for a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#searchfield").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "json/Providers.json",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    function (data) {
                        response(jQuery.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.ProviderID };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }); //end of jQuery.ajax({
            }
        })
```